# Programmatically created SKLabelNode not visible : SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Here's a code to my back button using SpriteKit, Swift 3

```
var backButton = SKLabelNode()
backButton.text = "Back"
backButton.name = "backbutton"
backButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.minX + 40, y: self.frame.maxY - 40)
backButton.fontColor = SKColor.red
backButton.fontSize = 30
self.addChild(backButton)
```

Comment: Not too familiar with SpriteKit, but while you've defined a **position** for this node, did you define a **frame**?

Comment: SKLabelNode is for label not a button .

Comment: SKLabelNode, @KKRocks, is perfectly capable of being a button, just as text is capable of being a button, and encouraged to be so throughout iOS. Further, as a subclass of SKNode, SKLabelNodes have all the touches responsive functions available to be overridden, precisely for this purpose.

Comment: You'll need to check other things, to find this problem. To start with, comment out the position while testing, and check your scene's origin/anchor point. Then try setting a high zPosition for your label, in case it's buried behind something in z space. If it's a child of another node and its opacity is reduced, this could be the problem. If you're declaring this within the context of another node, and that's not yet on a scene, this could explain it. There's other reasons, too. Can you provide a little more context, @DevWeby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you did wrong something like `zPosition`, `position` or where you add your label ( in what method and in what parent). Check out this example to see your label:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
     var backButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
     backButton.text = "Back"
     backButton.fontSize = 30
     backButton.name = "backbutton"
     backButton.fontColor = SKColor.red
     self.addChild(backButton) // self is GameScene (an SKScene)
     backButton.zPosition = 1
     backButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting label's alpha to 1, and Z position to any number:

```
backButton.alpha = 1
backButton.zPosition = 1
```

Hope this helps.